# Angular 2 routing onActivate

Tags: angular, typescript1.8

I'm trying to setup a component to use the routerOnActivate hook, but am getting an error "that property routerOnActivate is missing in component....' and the Component name 'SettingsHomeComponent' is underlined in red. This is also a child route...

```html
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {Routes, RouteSegment, RouteTree, ROUTER_DIRECTIVES, OnActivate} from '@angular/router';
import {SettingsProfileComponent} from '../profile/settings.profile.component';

@Component({
    selector: 'kg-Settings ',
    templateUrl: './app/components/settings/home/settings.home.component.html',
    directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES]
})

export class SettingsHomeComponent implements OnActivate{
 public isSettingsHome: boolean = false;
  
  routerOnAcivate(curr: RouteSegment, prev?: RouteSegment, currTree?: RouteTree, prevTree?: RouteTree) :void {
       
   }
}
```

Can anyone see the error or tell me what is wrong here...

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typo

```
routerOnAcivate
```

should be

```
routerOnActivate
```

(missing `t`)