# Implementing onActivate in a component

Tags: angular

I found many tutorials talking about the `onActivate` interface from `@angular/router`.

I'm using Angular 4 and this interface does not exist.

Is `onActivate` still exposed?

Comment: What tutorials? It seems like that was from v2 of the router, which was deprecated before Angular 2.0 went final: https://stackoverflow.com/q/37750552/3001761. I'd recommend finding more up-to-date resources.

Comment: Angular docs team is really great with their in depth explanation here are two links which helps you https://angular.io/api/router/CanActivate https://angular.io/guide/router#canactivate-requiring-authentication

Comment: This seems to address the deprecation history, it mentions the first deprecation, then the second with an update and links, https://stackoverflow.com/a/37304911/448144 hope it helps - Also, current documentation https://angular.io/guide/router

Comment: hey, did [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45077310/2545680) help?

Answer (score 0):

The interface you've probably read about is [canActivate](https://angular.io/api/router/CanActivate) and it still exists in the `@angular/router` package:

```
export interface CanActivate {
    canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean> | boolean;
}
```

However, it is **not** used on components but on the router guards:

```
import { CanActivate } from '@angular/router';

export class CanActivateGuard implements CanActivate {

}
```

Comment: I'm looking for onActivate and not canActivate. But I think that it was deprecated.

Comment: Can you reference the article where you found it?

Comment: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37796038/angular-2-routing-onactivate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37796038/angular-2-routing-onactivate) for example or this issue in Angular github [https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/6611](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/6611)

Answer (score 0):

You might be thinking of https://angular.io/api/router/RouterOutlet where `activate` is an event that is raised when a new component is placed in a router outlet.

In this example the `onActivate()` is just the function name - but could be anything.